# How to automatically convert a text file into a Graphviz DOT file?

Tags: graph, social-networking, graphviz, graph-visualization

I am using Graphviz as my visualization software for a network analysis program.The output of my program us a text file which contains edge connections between the nodes,but the input for Graphviz is a .dot format. so can anyone tell me how to convert .txt to .dot file or is there any software that can convert it into .dot format?
P.S. My ouptut file contain close to 8,000 nodes and working on windows platform.

Comment: Your question is not clear: What does your text file look like? Could you post an excerpt? A `.dot` file is simply a text file with a different extension.

Comment: The OP has given some information in a duplicate posting that was closed.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/9981705/181638  Seems his text format is *in matrix or edges format*.  Still ambiguous though.  As marapet has requested, an excerpt would make this easy to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to either

1. Modify the program which is producing said plain text output to produce a DOT output instead (which is also plain text, but adheres to a specific grammar)
2. Create a script which parses the plain text file output and converts it into DOT format.

If you post a snippet of the output file, we can help more.  This is probably a 2 or 3 line shell, awk, or python script.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the dot file format is a grammar as defined by 
http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html

And here is an example of it in use
http://www.graphviz.org/content/cluster

Comment: To elaborate on what RStrad says, the .dot format is just text. You declare your nodes and edges, and any additional formatting information, then Graphviz will turn it into a graph. You probably don't even need to name your text file as .dot, though it may make it easier to find / process later on.